# GCM push notification in android using .net webservice

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

MY server side code is in .net WCF.how can I implement GCM in my android java code.

I have tried with it GCm.Jar file with Jsp servlet.So want to do it with .net.
Please help me

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this post:

[HttpClient connecting to Https server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534697/httpclient-connecting-to-https-server/12534921#comment16895699_12534921)

It has an implementation of how to make Json Requests to a .Net WCF service.

Hope it helps, if you need further help, I can post some code.